# Inline a mega menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a [Wordpress site](https://mimsi.dk/), where I made a mega menu. I can see in the inspector window that the `div` tag where the mega menu is in, is inside the `navbar div` tag.

I need to place my menu like the below picture. I can do that with an `inline-block`, but then the menu options is laying on top of the logo, so the logo is not clickable.

How can I place my menubar between the logo and the basket, and still make the logo and basket clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox on the container which will position and space everything perfectly:

```
header .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Only problem is the shopping cart icon needs to be positioned 3rd in the HTML and remove the margin top

Comment: Ah ok that is pretty cool. I am gonna change to 3 position right away and see how it looks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is almost doing the job. If you look at the site now, then when the dropdown is showing the width are way to small now. 

Is it not possible to set some more width? Before there was much more width.

I can also see that the menu on mobile is centered now, and not working properly

Comment: It works just as it should. Add .'navbar-header { width:100%}', at least on mobile

Comment: ` .'navbar-header { width:100%}'` is solving the problem on mobile. But look the desktop view now.

Comment: Use a media query (replace 600px with the width you have it changing). media screen and (max-width: 600px) { .navbar-header { width:100%} }